# A problem on Alternating Current Related with Bulb's Brightness

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, inductance

I was going through some problems of Alternating Current [High School Level] and one of the questions asked

> 'A coil of self Inductance $L$ is connected in series with a bulb and An AC source. Brightness of the bulb decreases when' ...

I was able to think that to decrease the brightness, current should decrease, so, I was thinking how can I do that?

The answer given was : An Iron rod is inserted in the coil.

Looking forward for a answer, to explain this to me, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's like adding an iron core to an air core inductor which increases inductance. More inductance impedes AC current flow more so less current.

Comment: See also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductance

Comment: P.S., It's not _like_ adding an iron core to an air core inductor. It actually _is_ that.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I initially read the question as inserting an iron core into the filament coil; A daunting task.